# Tackling the 'Small Data' Problem with Distributed Computing Cluster?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm learning about `Hadoop + MapReduce and Big Data` and from my understanding it seems that the `Hadoop` ecosystem was mainly designed to analyze large amounts of data that's distributed on many servers. My problem is a bit different.

I have a relatively small amount of data (a file consisting of 1-10 million lines of numbers) which needs to be analyzed in millions of different ways. For example, consider the following dataset:

```
[1, 6, 7, 8, 10, 17, 19, 23, 27, 28, 28, 29, 29, 29, 29, 30, 32, 35, 36, 38]
[1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 10, 11, 12, 14, 16, 17, 18, 18, 20, 27, 28, 39, 40]
[2, 3, 7, 8, 10, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 15, 16, 17, 19, 27, 30, 32, 33, 34, 40]
[1, 9, 11, 13, 14, 15, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 23, 25, 26, 27, 31, 37, 39]
[5, 8, 8, 10, 14, 16, 16, 17, 20, 21, 22, 22, 23, 28, 29, 30, 32, 32, 33, 38]
[1, 1, 3, 3, 13, 17, 21, 24, 24, 25, 26, 26, 30, 31, 32, 35, 38, 39, 39, 39]
[1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 5, 10, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 17, 28, 29, 29, 35, 37, 40]
[1, 2, 6, 8, 12, 13, 14, 15, 15, 15, 16, 22, 23, 24, 26, 30, 31, 36, 36, 40]
[3, 6, 7, 8, 8, 10, 10, 12, 13, 17, 17, 20, 21, 22, 33, 35, 35, 36, 39, 40]
[1, 3, 8, 8, 11, 11, 13, 18, 19, 19, 19, 23, 24, 25, 27, 33, 35, 37, 38, 40]
```

I need to analyze how frequently a number of each column (`Column N`) repeats itself a certain number of rows later (`L rows later`. For example, if we were analyzing `Column A` with `1L` (1-Row-Later) the result would be as follows:

```
Note: The position does not need to match - so number can appear anywhere in the next row
Column: A N-Later: 1 Result: YES, NO, NO, NO, NO, YES, YES, NO, YES  -> 4/9.
```

We would repeat the above analysis for each column separately and for maximum N later times. In the above dateset which only consists of 10 lines it means a maximum of 9 N later. But in a dateset of 1 million lines, the analyses (for each column) would be repeated 999,999 times.

I looked into the `MapReduce` framework but it doesn't seem to cut it; it doesn't seem like an efficient solution for this problem and it requires a great deal of work to convert the core code into a `MapReduce` friendly structure.

As you can see in the above example, each analyses is independent of each other. For example, it is possible to analyze `Column A` separately from `Column B`. It is also possible to perform `1L` analyses separately from `2L` and so on. However, unlike `Hadoop` where the data lives on separate machines, in our scenario, each server needs access to all of the data to perform it's "share" of analysis.

I looked into possible solutions for this problem and it seems there are very few options: [Ray](https://github.com/ray-project/ray) or building a custom application on top of `YARN` using [Apache Twill](https://github.com/apache/twill). Apache Twill was [moved to the Attic](https://attic.apache.org/projects/twill.html) in 2020 which means that `Ray` is the only available option.

Is `Ray` the best way to tackle this problem or are there other, better options? Ideally, the solution should automatically handle fail over and distribute the processing load intelligently. For example, in the above example, if we wanted to distribute the load to 20 machines, one way of doing so would be to divide 999,999 N Later by 20 and let Machine A analyze 1L-49999L, Machine B from 50000L - 100000L and so on. However, when you think about it, the load isn't being distributed equally - as it takes **much** longer to analyze 1L vs. 500000L as the latter contains only about half the number of rows (for 500000L the first row we are analyzing is row 500001 so we are essentially omitting the first 500K rows from analysis).

It should also **not** require a great deal of modification to the core code (like `MapReduce` does).

I'm working with `Java`.

Thanks

Comment: Multithreading is how you distribute work on files. You don't need Hadoop or more than a single machine, even with 1 million lines https://adamdrake.com/command-line-tools-can-be-235x-faster-than-your-hadoop-cluster.html Even more importantly - If you're analyzing columns, use a columnar database or file format, not plaintext

Comment: @BenWatson yes, the data will fit in memory. Isn't Spark more suited when the data needs to be distributed in memory amongst multiple computers? In my case the data can fit in memory of one server, it just requires hours of computation. Would you still suggest using Spark over Ray in this case? Thanks!

Comment: @ErinParkinson Did you consider using Apache Spark?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thanks for the reference - it looks interesting. I believe one key difference between the example in the reference & this is the sheer number of calculations being performed. In a 1 million line file we are analyzing 999,999 N Later * 20 (20 columns). We are also performing a myriad of other calculations that's equivalent to billions or tens of billions of similar calculations (I cannot provide an exhaustive list of calculations due to complexity but it doesn't seem likely that one machine (even a high end one) will be able to pull this off within a few minutes.. Thanks!

Comment: Well, is each line the "same schema"? E.g. If you used Parquet files , then those columns are more easily computed against. Spark can still work on a single computer, as well. Though, Arrow or Dask should work, too... I don't have experience with Ray. But IMO,  "Hadoop core Mapreduce" should be avoided, if possible

Comment: @OneCricketeer yes, each line contains exactly the same number of columns and each column contains an integer (or more accurately an integer in the exact range of 1-40) so the data is very "coherent". Dask looks interesting but it is for python, not Java. It looks like Arrow has [a Java port](https://github.com/apache/arrow/tree/master/java) so that would be interesting. I agree to abandon MR as its not used anymore. I'd be curious if anyone had a Ray vs. Arrow vs. Spark comparison..

Answer (score 0):

Well you are right - your scenario and your technological stack are not that suitable. **Which raise the question** - why not (add) something more relevant to your current technological stack? For instance - Redis DB.

Seems that your common action is mainly count values and you want to prevent over-calculation and make it more performant (e.g. - properly index your data). Given that this is one of the main features of Redis - it sounds logical to use it as a processor

**My suggestion:**

Create a `hashmap` that uses the numeric value as key and its count as value. This way - you will be able to pull different calculations over those metrics and always iterate your data-set once. Afterwards - you just need to pull the data from Redis by different criteria (per calculation or metric).

From this point, it's easy to save your calculated data back to your database and make it ready for direct querying. The overall process may be similar to this:

- Scan data from file
- Properly index it to redis (using `hashmap`)
- Make desired calculations (over the indexed count)
- Save it in your DB (as a digested data-set)
- Flush Redis DB
- Query your DB (as much as you like)

Follow the docs for both [populating and retrieving](https://redis.io/commands/hset) data

Comment: Isn't `Redis` an in memory database solution? I don't see how it can solve/process complex calculations as defined in the OP (e.g, Did the number in Column A of Row 1 appear in any column of Row 2? Did the number in Column A of Row 1 appear in any column of Row 3? And so on..) If I'm misunderstanding the purpose of Redis please clarify what I am missing..

Comment: All your calculations are count based and can be indexed easily with redis. For each calculation you can use `hash` or simply `set` in order to properly index your data. Afterwards - move the results to your database and query as you desire. For more information about `Redis` behaviors with memory please follow https://docs.redis.com/latest/rs/concepts/memory-performance/